# When a user does not provide an input I'm getting "Segmentation fault: 11". It works fine when a user does provide an input. How can I fix this?

Tags: c, fgets

Its a `while (1)`-loop continuously asks user for input until terminated.
I want it to ask the user for an input and if no input is given upon pressing enter it should ask for the input again.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   char input[100];
   while (1) {
      fgets(input, 40, stdin);
   }
}
```

I've initialized input as `char input[100];` I also tried doing

```
char *input = (char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
```

but it does not help.

It works fine when a user provides input. How can I fix this?

Comment: Show us the minimum amount code that will allow us to replicate the problem. There's no way we can find bugs in code we can't even see!

Comment: int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char input[100];
       

        while (1) 
        { fgets(input, 40, stdin);}}

Comment: That code causes a segmentation fault?!

Comment: I've more code but shouldn't this portion be the one causing issue? Since it works fine when I DO get user input.

Comment: I have no way to know unless you give me code that you have confirmed replicates the issue. I really need the minimum amount of code necessary to replicate the problem and you need to confirm that it does in fact replicate the problem, otherwise, you're just guessing that it's sufficient to replicate the problem.

Comment: Remove the code you don't think matters rebuild and retry, then edit question above with the minimal example which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

From what I read this is what I think your program does

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   char input[100];
   while (1) {
      char* x=fgets(input, 40, stdin);
      printf("Hello%c\n",*x); 
   }
}
```

From the man page of fgets

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> `fgets()` returns s on success, and `NULL` on error or when end of file occurs while no characters have been read.

When `fgets()` encounters a end of file it returns a null pointer, if you try to follow it there will be a segmentation fault.

What you should do is check the return value

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   char input[100];
   char* x;
   while (x=fgets(input, 40, stdin)) {
      printf("Hello%x\n",x); 
   }
}
```

*Please note the assignment in `while (x=fgets(...))` is intended*